# SwiftUI How to return nil in alert message

Tags: networking, swiftui, null, alert

I am struggling with removing the successful message in the alert while checking the network status through the import network.

```
        .onAppear{
        viewModel.updateData(baseCode: viewModel.baseCode)
        
        if monitor.isConnected == false {
            print("Wifi is connected")
        } else if monitor.isConnected == true {
            self.showingAlert = true
        }
    }.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert, content: {
        if monitor.isConnected == false {
            return Alert(title: Text("Connect to Internet"), message: Text("Kindly Connect to internet to get the latest rates and use the application with accurate calculations"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Okay")))
        } else {
            return Alert(title: Text("Change Rate Updated"), message: Text("You have successfully updated the change rates."), dismissButton: nil)
        }
    })
```

I am trying to compile the code in the manner if everything is okay and i am connected to the Wi-fi instead of

```
return Alert(title: Text("Change Rate Updated"), message: Text("You have successfully updated the change rates."), dismissButton: nil)
```

I am trying to return nothing. So if there is a successful connection to the internet the message will not appear.

[image: Basically, I want to get rid of the message below. Please check the image attached as a reference.]

Comment: What do you mean by returning nil? Do you mean to alert only if you are not connected to WI-FI?

Comment: @mahan Yes exactly I want to represent an alert only in the case of unsuccessful internet connection for example if there is no internet connection I want to appear an alert but if there is a successful connection like cellular or WI-FI then an alert message should not appear.

Comment: @mahan Whenever I am trying to return nil its keeps asking me to return an alert. I will attach a screenshot now to my original question.

Comment: use the `alert(item:)`. There is a sample in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597744/swift-pass-json-data-to-other-views/68613840#68613840) on how to create an alert that shows custom messages

Answer (score 0):

`Alert` is only presened when `showingAlert` is true. Therefore, you do not need to use the `if-statement` in `.alert`

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert, content: {
   return Alert(title: Text("Connect to Internet"), message: Text("Kindly Connect to internet to get the latest rates and use the application with accurate calculations"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Okay")))
})
```

Test this code

```
struct OrderCompleteAlert: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert", action: {
            isPresented = true
        })
        .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Alert(title: Text("Order Complete"),
                  message: Text("Thank you for shopping with us."),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right to have only 1 option I have to avoid the if statement. But now, unfortunately, I don't know how it's showing an alert for both cases not only for when it's offline as well as when it's online.