# SwiftUI confirmationDialog on a full screen View?

Tags: swiftui

I'm experimenting with the `confirmationDialog` modifier (new in iOS 15). I thought I could use it like `sheet`, but it seems you have to attach it to a small view somewhere on the screen (at least on my iPad). Is there a way to make one appear unattached in the middle of the screen?

For example, this does *not* work on iPad. The dialog is invisible.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showConf = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
            Button("Test Conf. Dialog") {
                showConf = true
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.3))
        .confirmationDialog("Test", isPresented: $showConf) {
            Button("Yes") {
                print("Yes!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `confirmationDialog` is a `popover` [per Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:presenting:actions:)-9ibgk) and popovers in SwiftUI or UIKit have to be attached to a `sourceView` or you get some error saying that it isn't attached. You might be looking for an `Alert` vs a `confirmationDialog`. The effect/error is usually only visible in iPad or Mac.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I want an `alert` or a `sheet`. It appears that both `alert` and `confirmationDialog` limit the "message" part to a single text. I wanted more, so probably need the `sheet`. Unfortunately controlling the sheet size still seems to be a pain on iPad.

Comment: If you make a `CustomAlert` `struct`/`class` and use `.alert(item:)` you can change the `Alert` content to whatever you want. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597744/swift-pass-json-data-to-other-views/68613840#68613840) I wrote for another use case

Comment: The `Alert` struct is deprecated. If I use `alert(...)` modifier that takes the message as an argument, and I pass say a `VStack`, then it ignores all but the first `Text` in the stack. That's what I'm seeing now on my iPad, running iPadOS 15.

Answer (score 1):

try this, "attaching" the `confirmationDialog` to the `Button`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showConf = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
            Button("Test Conf. Dialog") {
                showConf = true
            }
            .confirmationDialog("Test", isPresented: $showConf) {
                Button("Yes") {
                    print("Yes!")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.3))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but my question was if there is a way to make one appear "unattached in the middle of the screen". I guess not. I need to use an `alert`, a `sheet`, or something custom. The sheet givse me another problem on iPad - I can't control the size ... but that's another stackoverflow question.